# HibernateSearch, JPA, H2 driver throws an exception during database indexing process

Tags: jpa, h2, hibernate-search

Using HibernateSearch I would like to index my H2 embeded database.
Invoking this code:

```
EntityManager em = articleDao.getEntityManager();
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
try {
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().progressMonitor(new CustomMassIndexerProcessMonitor()).startAndWait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After indexing a few minutes it throws following exception:

```
2013-09-04 09:01:41 ERROR LogErrorHandler.handleException():83 - HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000116: Unexpected error during MassIndexer operation
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.util.IOUtils.copyAndCloseInput(IOUtils.java:201)
    at org.h2.util.IOUtils.readStringAndClose(IOUtils.java:301)
    at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.getString(ValueLobDb.java:226)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcResultSet.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2912)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.java:151)
Hibernate Search: entityloader-2, CustomMassIndexerProcessMonitor entitiesLoaded(10)
Hibernate Search: collectionsloader-2, CustomMassIndexerProcessMonitor documentsAdded(1)
Hibernate Search: collectionsloader-2, CustomMassIndexerProcessMonitor documentsBuilt(1)
Hibernate Search: collectionsloader-3, CustomMassIndexerProcessMonitor documentsAdded(1)
Hibernate Search: collectionsloader-3, CustomMassIndexerProcessMonitor documentsBuilt(1)
2013-09-04 09:01:47 ERROR LogErrorHandler.handleException():83 - HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000116: Unexpected error during MassIndexer operation
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.util.IOUtils.readStringAndClose(IOUtils.java:302)
    at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.getString(ValueLobDb.java:226)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcResultSet.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2912)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.run(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:132)
```

It seems that one of H2 util class throws this exception when tries to read from DB. I have tried to increase heap using: '-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m', but this didn't help :(
The scenario is following. Each entry of my H2 database has a field type CLOB. If I write small content to this field then everything is fine, no errors are thrown.
But if I have big content in those fields (900kb each) then error is thrown during indexing process.

I am using following jars:
hibernate-entitymanager 4.2.4.Final 
h2  1.3.173 
hibernate-search    4.4.0.Alpha1

This is my persistence unit config:

```
<persistence-unit name="hibernateSearchH2TestPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <mapping-file>META-INF/queriesForTest.xml</mapping-file>

    <class>com.kaidex.db.entity.DocStatus</class>
    <class>com.kaidex.db.entity.DocType</class>
    <class>com.kaidex.db.entity.Article</class>
    <class>com.kaidex.db.entity.Issuer</class>
    <class>com.kaidex.db.entity.PublishingSource</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:D:\\kaidextestdb;CIPHER=XTEA"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="filepass userpass"/>

        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />


        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="D:\lucene"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.lucene_version" value="LUCENE_36"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Updated.** Added entities configuration:

```
@Entity(name="Article")
@Table(name="Article", schema="Kaidexdb")
@Indexed
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    ... 
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @Column(columnDefinition="CLOB")
    private String contentRo;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @Column(columnDefinition="CLOB")
    private String contentRu;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="docType_id", nullable=false)  
    private DocType docType;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="docStatus_id", nullable=false)    
    private DocStatus docStatus;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="issuer_id", nullable=false)
    private Issuer issuer;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ps_id", nullable=false)
    private PublishingSource publishingSource;
...


@Entity(name="DocStatus")
@Table(name="DocStatus", schema="Kaidexdb")
@Indexed
public class DocStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRo;
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRu;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="docStatus", targetEntity=Article.class)
    private List<Article> articles; 
...

@Entity(name="DocType")
@Table(name="DocType", schema="Kaidexdb")
@Indexed
public class DocType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String shortName;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRo;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRu;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="docType", targetEntity=Article.class)
    private List<Article> articles;
...


@Entity(name="Issuer")
@Table(name="Issuer", schema="Kaidexdb")
@Indexed
public class Issuer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String shortNameRo; 

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRo;  

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRu;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    @Column(name="parent_id")
    private long parentId; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="issuer", targetEntity=Article.class)
    private List<Article> articles;
...


@Entity
@Table(name="PublishingSource", schema="Kaidexdb")
@Indexed
public class PublishingSource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRo;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String longNameRu;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="publishingSource", targetEntity=Article.class)
    private List<Article> articles;
```

Could somebody help me with this problem? 
Maybe I should do some specific configurations to my H2 embeded database that will inform H2 that I use a big CLOB fields?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you also post how your entities are configured? Are you indexing the CLOBs? Are there (references) between the entities which results in loading multiple associated entities when indexing a single entity?

Comment: Thank you Hardy for the reply. I have added entities configuration above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved partially this issue. I have decreased the number of objects loaded by Hibernate Search per query:

```
EntityManager em = articleDao.getEntityManager();
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().batchSizeToLoadObjects(2).startAndWait();
```

It will be great if H2 developers would fix this issue in next releases.
I have tested same code with HSQLDB and Apache Derby, and those db drivers didn't throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace, Hibernate search tries to load the CLOB as a String from the database (using `java.sql.ResultSet.getString`). Because of that, H2 has to fully load the CLOB. Also, it looks like Hibernate Search keeps a list of such large Strings fully in memory:

```
at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.getString(ValueLobDb.java:226)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcResultSet.java:296)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:66)
...
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerEntityProducer.java:151)
```

So it looks like a problem in Hibernate Search. Memory issues related to Hibernate Search [have been reported before](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1011915) (I'm aware this was an old version), but what I would try first is use a different version of Hibernate Search, specially because you are using an Alpha version (4.4.0.Alpha1). Possibly it is known issue.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for so fast reply. I have changed Hibernate Search lib to: 'hibernate-search 4.3.0.Final' and 'hibernate-search 4.2.0.Final' but same error is thrown :(

Comment: Just to update some information. I have tested same code with other db drivers (HSQLDB, Apache Derby), and this exception is not reproduced.
I would like to use H2 database because it use less hard disk space then others embedded databases, and it is also faster then others.